# jenkins finished success while the make command failure

Tags: java, android, jenkins, makefile

I used jenkins to build android image nightly, and then found even the `make` and `cp` command failure,the jenkins still finished success.

The last build setup is to copy log file to job directory, so maybe it succeed，and then jenkins finished SUCCESS.

And the Text-finder plugin can only set build unstable not failure, so how to make the build failure when `make` fails.

The log is like this:

```
make: \*** No rule to make target \`device/vendor/product/google_frameworks/Google_Play.apk', needed by `out/target/product/device/system/app/Google_Play.apk'.  Stop.
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
target R.java/Manifest.java: FileBrowser(out/target/common/obj/APPS/FileBrowser_intermediates/src/R.stamp)
Warning: AndroidManifest.xml already defines versionCode (in http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android); using existing value in manifest. untranslatable but exists in locale 'zh_CN'
aapt: warning: string 'pref_development_uastring' has no default translation in packages/apps/Browser/res; found: zh_CN zh_TW
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
======================>End<=======================
cp: cannot stat `/home/jenkins/job_name/source/out/target/product/device/package.img': No such    file or directory
Extended Email Publisher is currently disabled in project settings
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Jenkins job is marked as successfull if the last command of the script has succeed.

A simple workaround is to specify `set -e` at the begginning of your bash script.

> -e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.

You can also specify a trap: `trap 'exit 1' ERR`, to stop the script if an error occurs.